# Converting SQL Query to LINQ for application

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I have a query in TSQL that I am trying to convert to LINQ for use in our web application, but I am really struggling with this one. It is MVC5 with EF6 and the database is SQL Server 2008 R2. Any help is appreciated!

**SQL Query**

```
select MAX(ShipFromCompanyName) as Supplier, COUNT(*) as AllSupplierCount, 
SUM(isnull(cast(TransportationCharges as decimal(18,2)),0)) as AllFreightCharges,
SUM(isnull(cast(TransportationCharges as decimal(18,2)),0)) * .45 as FreightSavings
from table
group by ShipFromCompanyName
order by ShipFromCompanyName
```

`ShipFromCompanyName` and `TransportationCharges` are both stored as varchar in the database, and unfortunately I am unable to change the data type of `TransportationCharge` to a decimal

**LINQ**

```
var Scorecard = (from upsid in _db.table select upsid).GroupBy(x => new { x.ShipFromCompanyName, x.TransportationCharges })
            .Select(x => new
            {
                x.Key.ShipFromCompanyName,
                SupplierCount = x.Count(),
                FreightCharges = x.Key.TransportationCharges.Cast<decimal>().Sum(),
            }).ToList();
```

Comment: have you tried `decimal.Parse()`?

Comment: Where would I put that? The part that I'm getting hung up on is the `SUM()` and `SUM() * .45` part of the normal SQL query.

Comment: What error message are you receiving?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are going to need to do it post processing and not have SQL do it.  Have SQL do as much as it can then do the rest in memory

```
var Scorecard = (from upsid in _db.table select upsid).GroupBy(x => new { x.ShipFromCompanyName, x.TransportationCharges })
        .Select(x => new
        {
            x.Key.ShipFromCompanyName,
            SupplierCount = x.Count(),
            FreightCharges = x.Key.TransportationCharges,
        }).AsEnumerable()
        .Select (x => new 
        {
            ShipFromCompanyName = ShipFromCompanyName ,
            SupplierCount = SupplierCount ,
            FreightCharges = FreightCharges.Cast<decimal>.Sum() ,
        }
```

Didn't test this code but it should give you the idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
var Scorecard = (from upsid in _db.table select upsid)
.GroupBy(x => new { x.ShipFromCompanyName, x.TransportationCharges })
.Select(x => new
{
    x.Key.ShipFromCompanyName,
    SupplierCount = x.Count(),
    FreightCharges = x.Key.TransportationCharges.Select(tc=>decimal.Parse(tc)).Sum()*0.45,
}).ToList();
```

Since I didn't understand your query clearly I am not sure, but this may work.